# Adding img attribute to options in b-select component

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I would like to add `HTML` img attribute to the `b-form-select` component of `boostrap-vue` inside to load img with each option?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options"></b-form-select>
    <div class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ selected }}</strong></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        selected: null,
        options: [
          { value: null, text: 'Please select some item' },
          { value: 'a', text: 'This is First option' },
          { value: 'b', text: 'Default Selected Option' },
          { value: 'c', text: 'This is another option' },
          { value: 'd', text: 'This one is disabled', disabled: true }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems bootstrap-vue and bootstrap have different implementations on select components. And bootstrap-vue doesn't support thumbnails and it uses native `select` and `options` elements which makes impossible to set background image. Instead you can emulate dropdown component like select as below :

> Template

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div class="back"></div>
    <b-dropdown :text="selected ? selected.text : 'Please select some item'">
      <b-dropdown-item
        :disabled="option.disabled"
        @click="select(option)"
        v-for="option in options"
        :key="option.value"
      >
        <div>
          <img :src="option.src">
          {{option.text}}
        </div>
      </b-dropdown-item>>
    </b-dropdown>
  </div>
</template>
```

> Component

```js
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      options: [
        {
          value: null,
          text: "Please select some item",
          src: "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png"
        },
        {
          value: "a",
          text: "This is First option",
          src: "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png"
        },
        {
          value: "b",
          text: "Default Selected Option",
          src: "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png"
        },
        {
          value: "c",
          text: "This is another option",
          src: "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png"
        },
        {
          value: "d",
          text: "This one is disabled",
          disabled: true,
          src: "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    select(option) {
      console.log(option);
      this.selected = option;
    }
  }
};
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-dropdown-select-emulation-vg82g-vg82g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: it doesn't work the image doesn't showing up even if the img is injected inside the option

Comment: @InvokeMyName i made a bad assumption. See my accepted answer.

Comment: BootsrapVue uses the same CSS as Bootstrap to generate the custom styled selects.  Both are based on the native browser `<select>` element

Answer (score 0):

Just like Bootstraps's custom select component BootstrapVue's `<b-form-select>` is based on `<select>`, which by HTML5 standards does not support complex HTML content in `<option>` elements.

If you need complex content (i.e. images, etc) in the options, you would need to create a custom component (probably based on `<b-dropdpwn>`) that allows you to use custom HTML5 in the "options" (dropdown items) and emulate the native select features.